# how to catch all inside pre element with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having a block of code which is in a pre element with a class and an uniqueId.
This is part of the php and the javascript which creates it:

```
 $Result = "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     var pp = false;

     $('.Message').livequery(function () {

        $('pre', this).addClass('prettyprint$Class');
        $('pre').uniqueId();
```

What I want to achieve: just one click and everything inside the codeblock must be selected (like image below). How can I do that?

[image: how it should be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z5anL4v1/1/

HTML:

```
<pre id="test">
    var x = 10;
    console.log(x);
</pre>
```

JS:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
$(test).on('click', function () {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(test);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
});
```